# automata accepting only ba^(n) for n>=1, odd n using 2 states

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

There was a question on my exam asking to draw an automata with `2 states ("O" and "E")` with the final state accepting `ba^(n)`, `for n>=1` and n had to be an odd number. I spent **45 minutes** on it and I don't even think I got it right.

How would you draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use Myhill-Nerode to prove that was has been requested is impossible. We can illustrate the equivalence classes w.r.t. the indistinguishability relation taken for this language.

Consider the empty string, `e`. It can be followed by any string in `L` to get a string in `L`. Therefore we have an equivalence class `[e]` corresponding to the initial state of the automaton. Note that this state is not accepting since `e` is not a string in the language.

Consider the string `a`. This can not be followed by any string to get a string in `L`, and so this is a different equivalence class `[a]`. Clearly `a` is not a string in the language and so this is not accepting. This cannot be the same state as corresponds to `[e]`; indeed, the state corresponding to `[e]` transitions to the state corresponding to `[a]` on the input `a`.

We now have two distinct non-accepting states that must appear in any minimal DFA recognizing `L`. Since `L` is non-empty (left as an exercise) there must be some other accepting state(s) in any minimal DFA. Therefore, there is non two-state DFA accepting `L`. QED

Continuing the analysis, the equivalence classes are `[e]`, `[a]`, `[b]` and `[ba]`. The transition table is:

```
q     s    q'
[e]   a    [a]
[e]   b    [b]
[a]   a    [a]
[a]   b    [a]
[b]   a    [ba]
[b]   b    [a]
[ba]  a    [b]
[ba]  b    [a]
```

The only accepting state is the one corresponding to `[ba]`.

Comment: That's what I thought. I tried maybe 20 different automatas and nothing worked. That's kind of sneaky to ask an impossible question in a mid term exam haha. Thanks!